# Gradle dependency NoSuchMethodError 'AnnotationAttributes.getAliasedStringArray'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, build.gradle

I'm building a sftp upload and download project with spring integration in intellij and i'm having problems  with these methods: ObjectUtils.unwrapOptional, AnnotationAttributes.getAliasedStringArray. When i run the project i get the NoSuchMethodError error for one of the methods mentioned above. I'm not finding a spring-core jar that contains both of them, the current jar i'm using in gradle is: 'compile group: org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE' which doesn't contain the **getAliasedStringArray** method at AnnotationAttributes class. Can somebody help me with the version of the jar which contains both methods? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotationAttributes.getAliasedStringArray` was depreciated as of [4.3.6.RELEASE](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/deprecated-list.html) and was replaced by `AnnotationAttributes.getStringArray` (check out the specification for [5.0.8.RELEASE](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes.html)).

Essentially, you'll either have to change the implemenation to the new method as the ***deprecated*** method is not in the version your using or you'll have to down grade your version.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i down grade the version, then the jar will not have the unwrapOptional method of the ObjectUtils class, i need both of them

Comment: Then I would suggest updating your implementation to use `AnnotationAttributes.getStringArray`